# Object spawn timing causing scrolling background freeze

Tags: java, timer, libgdx, horizontal-scrolling

I am attempting to spawn an object every 10 seconds, which enters from left of screen and terminates when it reaches right of screen, or on intersection with my other rectangle.

I have been able to spawn the object every 3 seconds or more, but if I try to spawn the object any less frequently, my scrolling background freezes for an amount of time (measurable to the object spawn time I have set). Note that other parts of my game remain unaffected (e.g. my object animation still works fine).

I am guessing the timing schedule of my spawning object is interfering with the timing schedule of my scrolling background, but I can't figure out exactly how this is happening.

My spawning object time schedule is set using this approach (note that spawnObject is the name of the method that creates the object rectangle, which is part of an array):

```java
private long lastObjectTime;

lastObjectTime = TimeUtils.millis();
if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastObjectTime > 3000) spawnObject();
```

My scrolling background time schedule is set using this approach:

```java
private float currentBgX;
private float currentBgX1;
private long lastTimeBg;

// background separator for 800x480 background .ong
currentBgX = 800;
currentBgX1 = 800;

// set background to current time 
lastTimeBg = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

// move the separator every 100000 nanoseconds
if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastTimeBg > 1000000)
{
// move the separator 1px; 4px
currentBgX -= 1;
currentBgX1 -= 4;
lastTimeBg = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

// if the separator reaches the edge, move it back to the start
if(currentBgX == 0)
  currentBgX = 800;
if(currentBgX1 == 0)
  currentBgX1 = 800;
```

Note that I have tried using an alternate timing schedule for my spawning object to avoid interference with my scrolling background time schedule. I tried this:

```java
float timer = 0f;

if (timer >= 3f) 
{
spawnObject();
timer = 0f;
}
```

The spawning object timing schedule directly above had exactly the same effect as the first timing schedule (based on TimeUtils.millis(); )

Does anyone know how I can make the objects spawn less frequently (i.e. more than 3 seconds apart) without having my scrolling background freeze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
lastObjectTime = TimeUtils.millis();
if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastObjectTime > 3000) spawnObject();
```

You are setting lastObject to the current time, then immediately afterwards you are getting the difference (which will be very very small) and seeing if it's greater than 3 seconds (probably won't be).

Regardless, I would suggest creating a Spawner class which simply updates every time through the loop with a deltaTime. It will manage its own spawn timers accordingly there and act appropriately. Create another class for your background and it will do the same. Both of these will be contained in a "world" class which will also update based on a deltaTime. This way everything is separate and you shouldn't have to worry about these kinds of problems. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! I'm working on creating the Spawner and Background classes now, as I originally had everything in one big bulky class. With my two new classes (plus my original game class) I am not yet able to see the background or the spawning objects, but I'm working on it. I'm also working on using one timer for all my objects. I'll get back to you when I've been able to make your solution work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of this `if` statement?

```
// set background to current time 
lastTimeBg = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

// move the separator every 100000 nanoseconds
if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastTimeBg > 1000000)
{
```

Do you really want to see if it took 100000 nanoseconds to get from the the line before the `if` to the `if` itself?

Oh and try just using `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing this out. You're right, it doesn't really seem to have a point. I'm working on using the same timer for all objects at the moment. I'll see how this goes.